# Can't get Vue.js CSS transition to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, vue.js

Documentation for CSS transitions can be found [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html).

Pretty sure I set up my JSFiddle exactly how it needs to be set up for the transition to work. Not entirely certain because imo the documentation is a little light on CSS transitions.

Have some very basic HTML/CSS I was hoping would enable Vue.js to create a nice fade effect:

CSS:

```
.fade-transition {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .45s linear;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loading-overlay" v-if="loading" v-transition="fade">
  In 5 seconds, this overlay should fade out...
</div>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Any advice?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qpkft43/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `transition` attribute in your `div` tag, simply remove the `v-` from before the `transition` and it'll work.

```
<div class="loading-overlay" v-if="loading" transition="fade">
  In 5 seconds, this overlay should fade out...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change v-transition to just **transition**.

```
<div class="loading-overlay" v-if="loading" transition="fade">
  In 5 seconds, this overlay should fade out...
</div>
```